# Getting pattern string from java SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have a SimpleDateFormat object that I retrieve from some internationalization utilities. Parsing dates is all fine and good, but I would like to be able show a formatting hint to my users like "MM/dd/yyyy". Is there a way to get the formatting pattern from a SimpleDateFormat object?

Answer (score 36):

[`SimpleDateFormat.toPattern()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#toPattern%28%29)

> Returns a pattern string describing
>   this date format.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't look close enough.

Comment: Can you tell me, how to get just the date or time pattern from this string? I can use String methods like compare and contains, but is there a more elegant method than doing this?

Answer (score 6):

If you just need to get a pattern string for the given locale, the following worked for me:

```
/* Obtain the time format per current locale */

public String getTimeFormat(int longfmt) {
Locale loc = Locale.getDefault();
int jlfmt = 
    (longfmt == 1)?java.text.SimpleDateFormat.LONG:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.SHORT;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
    (SimpleDateFormat)SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(jlfmt, loc);
return sdf.toLocalizedPattern();
}

/* Obtain the date format per current locale */

public String getDateFormat(int longfmt) {
Locale loc = Locale.getDefault();
int jlfmt = 
    (longfmt == 1)?java.text.SimpleDateFormat.LONG:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.SHORT;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
    (SimpleDateFormat)SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(jlfmt, loc);
return sdf.toLocalizedPattern();
}
```

getDateInstance and getTimeInstance for the given locale are key here.

Answer (score 5):

Use `toPattern()` or `toLocalizedPattern()` method.

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Sdf {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        String patternToUse = sdf.toPattern();
        System.out.println( patternToUse );
    }
}
```