# Android: Get local date format as it is in String with letters, not numbers

Tags: java, android, date, locale

I want to get local date format. I mean I want that method (or list of methods) which would return String which would be `yyyy-MM-dd`, if it is LT; `yyyy/MM/dd` if it is EN and so on. I don't need exact numbers like `2001/02/26`, but only format. How can I get that?

Comment: [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) will format time/date suitably in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class SimpleDateFormat contains a method toPattern that might be useful to you.  Your question is similar to the one in [Getting pattern string from java SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761442/getting-pattern-string-from-java-simpledateformat), where there is more information.