# How to get locale specific Date/Time patterns in Java in a future-proof way

Tags: java, datetime

TL;DR: How do I get **from** having locale and SHORT/MEDIUM/LONG etc **to** the *pattern String* to parse a date.

Full version:

Accessing the *pattern* of a locale-specific date format seems to be problem not well covered in Java.

This is in the context of

- the JDK8+ DateTime API [not providing access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28949179/13447), and
- the [classic SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2761442/13447) not looking future-proof enough.

I'm bringing this question back due to the JDK-specificity of the first, and the implementation-specific-ness of the second question, this time to be answered in a non-version-specific way, long after 2017 (the date of the first question):

Use case:

On the user interface, show the date format that a date will be parsed with, when entered: E.g. For `Locale.US` display `start date (M/d/yy)`, for `Locale.GERMANY` show `Startdatum (dd.MM.yy)` next to an input (or, in HTML, as a placeholder).

This would be trivial to achieve - *as long as it still works* - with

```
DateFormat usFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.US);
DateFormat deFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.GERMANY);
System.out.println(((SimpleDateFormat) usFormat).toPattern()); // M/d/yy
System.out.println(((SimpleDateFormat) deFormat).toPattern()); // dd.MM.yy
```

but this code involves the old API and an implementation specific typecast - both are assumptions that I'm not too confident using.

Maintaining my own library of locale-specific patterns seems even less advisable, but with the DateTime API not granting any access to its internal patterns (they *must* be there):

Is there a way to solve this problem in a future-proof way?

Due to the linked questions above, this likely involves a specific minimal Java version, and that's fine. I'm currently still bound to be 8 and 11 compatible, but this could either push the version further, or provide an alternative future proof implementation for instances running under newer Java versions.

Comment: Yes, I know. But that doesn't give me access to the underlying PATTERN - which is what this problem is about. Added a tl;dr

Comment: @Jens that's the non-futureproof, implementation dependent outdated version that I write about in the question, trying to replace it with a future-proof implementation

Comment: As an aside, for presentation to the user you might have wanted `SimpleDateFormat.toLocalizedPattern()`. It produces a string where in English `y` for year is used and in German `j` for Jahr, etc. Unfortunately I know of no modern counterpart. I agree to avoid using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to get the format string:

```
String usFormat = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.SHORT, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.US);
String deFormat = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.SHORT, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.GERMANY);
System.out.println(usFormat); // M/d/yy
System.out.println(deFormat); // dd.MM.yy
```

Comment: Nice - exactly what I've looked for. And the length of the source line indicates why it's so hard to find...